# Windsor resolving IViewEngine in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, castle-windsor

Have this in Global.asax using windsor 2.5.1.0

```
_windsor.Register(
    Component.For<IViewEngine>().ImplementedBy<RazorViewEngine>(),
);
```

When executing this right after:

```
IViewEngine tt2 = _windsor.Resolve<IViewEngine>();
int count = ((RazorViewEngine) tt2).ViewLocationFormats.Length;
```

The count variable is 0, but with this:

```
IViewEngine tt2 = new RazorViewEngine();
int count = ((RazorViewEngine) tt2).ViewLocationFormats.Length;
```

It is 4, which is the default. I cannot see why the windsor instance is returning zero?

Anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: I had before the registers: 

    container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new ArrayResolver(container.Kernel, true));

Which gave the error. Works now.

Comment: Please make that comment an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had before the registers:

```
container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new ArrayResolver(container.Kernel, true));
```

Which gave the error. Wo